# Logstash Convert List to Object

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

If send following data to Logstash:

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": 2,
"c": 3,
"d": {
      ["key": "felan", "value": 123], ["key": "bahman", "value":321]
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
{
"a": 1,
"b": 2,
"c": 3,
"d": {
      "felan": 123, 
      "bahman": 321
    }
}
```

How should I write the filter in Logstash?

Comment: The data you're receiving, it's a text field in your logstash event? Do the number of key-value elements can change?